# Issue with background in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I'm creating a collection view, where on the scroll of each cell the collection view background changes to a image I have. The issue is the bg changes before the cell is even in the view. How do I fix this?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    cell.cellNavTitle.text = appConfig.menuItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.cellNavImage.image = UIImage(named: (appConfig.icon[indexPath.row]))
    cell.cellNavDescription.text = appConfig.title[indexPath.row]

    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "1414441938milaj_bg2")!)
      break
    case 1:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      break
    case 2:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
      break
    default:
      break
    }

    return cell       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If matthias methos is not working try to use scrolling delegates. Where you can set exact height you want and change the back ground as you want. Try this one :- Put you logic in  If condition. In here i just set a logic which check the scrolling height.

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if contentOffset < 500 {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "1414441938milaj_bg2")!)
    } else if contentOffset < 700 {
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   } else if contentOffset < 900 {
       collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
   }
}
```

change contentOffset value according to your collection view heights

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this delegate:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
             willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell,
          forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

> The collection view calls this method before adding a cell to its
>   content. Use this method to detect cell additions, as opposed to
>   monitoring the cell itself to see when it appears.

i.e.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                 willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell,
              forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "1414441938milaj_bg2")!)
      break
    case 1:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
      break
    case 2:
      collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
      break
    default:
      break
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I put it in that method at first, the moment the app THINKS the cell is going to come up, it changes the background. It does not even wait for the cell to come into view.